# How can I create a TabbedPage from data brought from a web service without blocking the user interface?

Tags: xamarin.forms, async-await

I am trying to create a TabbedPage within a MasterDetailPage from data brought from a web service.
The issue with this is that I am blocking the user interface because I have to wait for the task that JSON brings to then iterate it and create the corresponding ViewModels for each ContentPage of the TabbedPage.

My code is something like:
Mi TabbePage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyProject.Views.MyTabbedPage"
             ItemSource={Binding Tabs}>
    <TabbedPage.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPage Title={Binding Description}>
                ...
            </ContentPage>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabbedPage.ItemTemplate>

</TabbedPage>
```

My TabbedPageViewModel:

```
public TabbedPageViewModel()
        {
            var task = Task.Run(async () => { await LoadThings(); });
            Task.WaitAll(task);
            Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabbedPageDetailViewModel>();
            foreach (var t in Things)
            {
                Tabs.Add(new TabbedPageDetailViewModel(t.IdCode, t.Description));
            }
        }


        private async Task LoadThings()
        {
            Things = new List<Thing>(await App.WebApiManager.GetCustomerThingsAsync(App.User.IdCustomer));
        }
```

My TabbedPageDetailViewModel:

```
public TabbedPageDetailViewModel(string idCode, string description)
        {
            IdCode = idCode;
            Description = description;
            Task task1 = Task.Run(async () => await LoadTask1(idCode));
            var task2 = Task.Run(async () => { await LoadTask2(idCode); });
            Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
        }


        private async Task LoadTask1(string idCode)
        {
            //await code that brings API data to load controls
        }

        private async Task LoadTask(string idCode)
        {
            // await code that brings API data to load controls
        }
```

All this code blocks the user interface while the data is consumed from the API.
How can I implement this in a correct synchronous way which allows my interface to remain reactive?
PS: I can download my collection of Things in the login process of my app but I still get some delay when TabbedPageDetailViewModel is being instantiated.

Comment: You can add a [activityindicator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/activityindicator) when loading those tasks. You have to wait those tasks because you need the data from api to create the corresponding ViewModels for each ContentPage of the TabbedPage.

Comment: I can't put an activityindicator because an activityindicator is a view and tabbedpage requires a collection of contentpages.

Comment: you should create a placeholder page that displays a loading message while the data is gathered, then navigate to the TabbedPage once the data is loaded

Comment: I tried this approach, but it is not possible to automatically navigate the page with the activity indicator to the tabbedpage without user intervention

Comment: @lavilaso this is just not true.

Comment: @Jason I have managed to make this approach moderately work. I manage to make the loading page appear with the activity indicator and from that page I push the tabbedpage, but despite the fact that I manage to show the activity indicator the user interface thread is blocked while the PushAsync is being done showing the activity indicator with its animation but not allowing to see the hamburger menu.

Comment: @Jason  have also tried to add logic that installs my problematic viewmodel on the loading page and at the time of doing PushAsync pass it to the next page through the constructor, in the constructor I send a message via MessagingCenter that notifies the end of the constructor and on the load page Subscribe to this message and right there it does the PushAsync but I notice that the message arrives very fast, just when instantiating the viewmodel that is supposed to take seconds to bring data and in the end you never navigate to the next page.

Comment: you don't need to use the ActivityIndicator - just show a page that says "Loading Data" and nothing else

Comment: @Jason Ok. This will result in the same behavior as indicated by the activity indicator. If the loading message will be seen but the interface loses its reactivity completely and it is not possible to manipulate the hamburger menu while the control is passed to my page where I show the data.

Answer (score 0):

How about add the activityindicator in the contentPage?  For example:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             x:Class="App526.TabbedPage1">
  <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
    <ContentPage Title="{Binding des}" >
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="true" x:Name="page1ActIndictor" />
    </ContentPage>

    <ContentPage Title="{Binding name}" >
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="true" x:Name="page2ActIndictor" />
    </ContentPage>

    <ContentPage Title="{Binding age}" >
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="true" x:Name="page3ActIndictor" />
    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

And in your code behind, use messagingCenter to stop the activityindicator :

```
public TabbedPage1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "dataLoadFinish", (sender) =>
    {
        page1ActIndictor.IsRunning = false;
        page2ActIndictor.IsRunning = false;
        page3ActIndictor.IsRunning = false;
    });
}
```

Send the message when loading finished:

```
public class TabbedPageDetailViewModel 
{
    //...
    public void loadingTask() {

        //After finish loading data

        MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(this, "dataLoadFinish");
    }    
    //...
}
```

Comment: This approach is not viable because the titles of the contentpages that are daughters of my tabbedpage also depend on data brought from the API, so when trying this I also receive delay in the construction and blocking of the user interface

Comment: How did you show the  titles of the contentpages if you don't have data from the API? Maybe put a placeholder? You have no choice but to have the delay  in the construction and blocking of the user interface.

Comment: The last approach I tried is to create a loading page with an activity indicator which is called before my TabbedPage, this page instantiates the viewmodel of my TabbedPage and through an event that my LoagindPage subscribes to when it has finished loading everything my viewmodel, right at that moment I do the PuashAsync (new Tabbedpage (viewmodel)), but for some reason this approach also blocks the user interface.